# Creating async method using CodeMemberMethod

Tags: c#, template-meta-programming, codedom

How does one adorn a method signature with `async` using the `CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod`?

i want to have as a result:

```
public async Task SomeMethodAsync()
{     
}
```

There is no way to do this whis CodeDom. I ended up using `regex`.

```
 public static class GenCodeParser
 {
    private const string AsyncKeyWordPattern = @"(?<=public class DynamicClass(\r\n)*\s*{(\r\n)*\s*public)(?=.*\s*SomeMethodAsync{1})";
    private const string AsyncKeyWordReplacementPattern = @" async ";

    public static string AddAsyncKeyWordToMethodDeclaration(string sourceCode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceCode)) return null;

        try
        {
            var regex = new Regex(AsyncKeyWordPattern);
            return regex.Replace(sourceCode, AsyncKeyWordReplacementPattern);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your found a solution, you should post it as an answer and then you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeDOM doesn't know anything about `async`, so there is no direct way to add that to your method. But it's also pretty lenient about what it lets your write.

So, what you can do is to write a method whose return type is `async Task`. Of course that's not a valid type, but if you write that string to where the return type normally is, you get what want.

For example:

```
new CodeMemberMethod
    { Name = "M", ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference("async Task") }
```

Compiles into:

```
private async Task M() {
}
```